# php/CSS formatting

Tags: php, css

We have changed hosting providers for our php/css website.

On the new providers server the formatting for the site looks a bit odd. ie the text is not correct and the titles are not in the correct place. All of the files have been uploaded including the CSS files.

Is there anything we should look for? maybe permissions? any help would be great never mind how simple.

Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell anything without seeing the site.

Comment: It's possible one of the files was corrupted during the upload. (It happens, but it's pretty rare.) As such, you might want to try re-pushing all the CSS files first. (Unless of course you dynamically include CSS files via PHP, in which case that might be a good place to check first.)

Comment: Agreed - you'll get a pretty swift answer if you can show us the two sites.

Comment: Any ideas with this one with the links above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting multiple CSS errors off your "migrated" site in the Firefox error console: bad selectors, bad font names, etc.. But some of  these errors don't occur on the old site.

In other words, your new site isn't identical to the old one.

The big one is that your `/styles/stylesheet.css` is actually a PHP file, with the raw PHP code being served up instead of CSS:

```
<?php 

header("Content-type: text/css; charset=UTF-8");

$default = array(
    'fontSize' => '75%'
);
```

The syntax errors are killing most of the CSS rules, which explains the differences.

Comment: Odd as we have sync'ed the sites. We have even re-uploaded the CSS.

Comment: You'll have to tell the webserver that that particular css file (or all css files in general) should be treated as PHP scripts instead. On Apache, it'd be someting like `AddType application/x-httpd-php .css`

Answer (score 1):

Is the php version on the new server the same as on the old version?

I wouldn't expect minor differences in version to affect anything, but major differences in versions may cause unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

can you do a diff on the html source from the previous host and the new server. This assumes you still have access to the html on the old server.

Answer (score 0):

Check all the files have been uploaded correctly (well all the css files) its possible there was an error and only a partial file was uploaded

Answer (score 0):

View the HTML source and see what the referenced CSS files are. Try to load each one individually. If any fails, it means you have an access rights problem.

Comment: There is only one CSS and it loads fine